# How to get AWS SES template to use parameters in the "HTMLPart":

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ses

How can i get the {{name}} and {{favoriteanimal}} parameter to work, i have a custom html file that has been escaped to use in the .json format. When adding in my parameters to the html like the template below my emails do not send, when i take out the parameters from my hmtlpart my email then sends just fine. I am able to successfully get the subject {{name}} parameter to work but am struggling on getting the html parameters to work. I do have my parameters in the json file i am using to send the email in the TemplateData section.

```
{
      "Template": {
        "TemplateName": "MyTemplate",
        "SubjectPart": "Greetings, {{name}}!",
        "HtmlPart": "<h1>Hello {{name}},</h1><p>Your favorite animal is {{favoriteanimal}}.</p>",
        "TextPart": "Dear {{name}},\r\nYour favorite animal is {{favoriteanimal}}."
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `<table>` tags on the html,
than you're good to go with the `send_template_email` method on boto3 like this:

```
    some_var_val = "kfjh23498h24hw"
    
    ses_client.send_templated_email(
      Source='your@from.email',
      Destination={
          'ToAddresses': [
              'your@to.email'
          ]
      },
      Template='your-exact-template-name',
      TemplateData='{"some_var_key": "'+some_var_val+'"}'
    )
```

Take a look here:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_templated_email